# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy

Tags: apache-spark

1. I processing the csv file from Spring Batch java application to spark cleaning.
2. cleaned files writing to parquet in cluster.
3. getting Serialization exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This ain't a nice way to ask questions. I think you should have a look at the help me section first. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error message when running this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

val txt = Array("A B B C", "A B D D", "A C D")
val txtDf     = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(txt).toDF("txt")
val txtDfSplit = txtDf.withColumn("txt", split(col("txt"), " "))

// val txtDfSplit = df.withColumn("txt", split(col("txt"), " "))

// create sparse vector with the number 
// of occurrences of each word using CountVectorizer
val cvModel = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("txt").setOutputCol("features").setVocabSize(4).setMinDF(2).fit(txtDfSplit)

val txtDfTrain = cvModel.transform(txtDfSplit)
txtDfTrain.show(false)
```

Produces this error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 9 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.3
>   in stage 1.0 (TID 25, somehostname.domain, executor 1):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
>   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of
>   type scala.collection.Seq in instance of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

I have been looking through various pages describing this error and it seems to be some kind of version conflict. The code works in IntelliJ (stand alone). I get the error when the app is submitted to Spark.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am running into the same error.